# Not able to add Google Plus Page ID to Developer Console

Tags: google-api, google-plus, over-the-air

Adding my Google plus page ID to developer console throws following error:

```
The Google+ Page ID does not exist. Please make sure you do not link to a profile ID.
```

Even though the page ID is correct and the url 'http://plus.google.com/' works correctly.

Comment: Have you successfully added your community/page id yet? I'm having this issue aswell.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](https://plus.google.com/102903603791037724851/posts/C31vsWsjKQe) that should now be fixed.

Comment: Thanks @abraham i had the same issue. Thank for your link